# Criptografia md5 PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, criptografia

Estou criando uma tabela usando o PostgreSql e na mesma haverá um campo senha com criptografia MD5. Como ficaria a sintaxe nela? Pois tenho mais contato com o MySQL do que o PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize:

```
MD5('String')
```

Por exemplo:

```
INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('Luiz', MD5('Segredo'));
```